# An Incorrect Solution to Hartshorne Ex. III.5.5(c).

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fake-proofs

Let $X:=\mathbb{P}^r_k$ and $Y$ a closed subscheme of dimension $q$ which is a complete intersection. The reader is asked to show $H^i(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y(n))=0$ for all $0<i<q$ and all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

The following fake proof yields *too much information,* and my suspicion is that the initial step is incorrect. *I would like an explanation on what is wrong.* I have bolded the part that I suspect is faulty. Indeed, I think the cohomology of $i_*\mathcal{O}_Y(n)$ may not be the cohomology group $H^i(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y(n))$...

**Look at the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathscr{I}_Y\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow i_*\mathcal{O}_Y\rightarrow 0$ where $i:Y\hookrightarrow X$. Now twist this by $n$ to get $0\rightarrow \mathscr{I}_Y(n)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(n)\rightarrow i_*\mathcal{O}_Y(n)\rightarrow 0$.** Take the long exact sequence of cohomology,

$$0\rightarrow H^0(X,\mathscr{I}_Y(n))\rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow\dots H^i(X,\mathscr{I}_Y(n))\rightarrow H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X(n))\rightarrow H^i(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y(n))\rightarrow H^{i+1}(X,\mathscr{I}_Y(n))\rightarrow\dots $$

Now the sheaf $\mathscr{I}_Y(n)$ is quasi-coherent since $\mathscr{I}_Y$ is quasi-coherent and $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$ is invertible. So Serre's Criterion says all higher cohomology vanishes. Since we know $H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X(n))=0$ for all $0<i<r$, we then obtain $H^i(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y(n))=0$ for all $0<i<r$ as well.

Edit: This method would also give part (a) of the problem for free, but again, it appears faulty.

Comment: Which Serre's criterion are you using?

Comment: Where have you used $Y$ is a complete intersection?

Comment: @KarlKroningfeld I just realized in hindsight that nothing here is affine. Doh!

Comment: @Mohan Nowhere -- and I realized I completely forgot that Serre's criterion required affineness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very short answer which I realized from a comment of @Karl Kroningfeld

The solution is incorrect because Serre's Criterion requires that scheme to be affine. This is not true in this case.

Comment: It doesn’t “require” affineness, the point is that it is, well, a criterion for it. It holding it equivalent to being affine.

Comment: @StefanDawydiak Yes, but in the manner the false proof was given only one direction would've been warranted.